# how to read a quicktime header with python

Tags: python, header, quicktime

I want to get the original creation date of quicktime videos created on my Canon 60d for use in a python script I've written to help me sort my movies. How can I get at the information stored in quicktime headers with python?

If there's nothing existing in vanilla python to help me, I thought I might [give this a whirl](http://code.google.com/p/videoparser/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

videoParser works well. I remember trying it out. If for any reason that does not satisfy your needs, try this http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hachoir-metadata/1.2.1

Comment: videoParser didn't give me any useful results (came back with "failed"). Hachoir on the other hand is working nicely for me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @sfillat glad I could help. If my answer has helped you please upvote & accept my answer (by clicking little arrow on the left) in the spirit of stackoverflow community....